# Flask inherited classes of tables in multiple identical databases using __bind_key__

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to build an admin control panel that brings together 4 different ecommerce sites. The sites all have identical database structures (all MySQL).

## What's Going Wrong?

I get 404 Not Found on any order ID and site I put in. No matter how I mix it I can not get any record to come up. Always a 404 and I have no idea why. SO here I am.

## Code

I tried to do this by creating base model classes of every table. Then creating inherited clases of those base classes with a different bind key dependent on the DB it is meant for. This is a summarised view of the code - if you'd need anymore than this let me know:

### basemodels.py

```
MyOrderClass(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'messytablename'
    id = db.Column('order_id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    order_total = db.Column(db.Float)
    order_status = db.Column(db.String(1))
```

### site2models.py

```
class Site2Order(MyOrderClass):
    __bind_key__ = 'site2'
```

### __init__.py

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://user:pass@localhost/site'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_BINDS'] = {
    'site1':'mysql://user:pass@localhost/site1',
    'site2':'mysql://user:pass@localhost/site2',
    'site3':'mysql://user:pass@localhost/site3',
    'site4':'mysql://user:pass@localhost/site4'
}
```

### views.py

```
@app.route('/order/<site>/<orderid>')
def show_order(site, orderid):
    if site == 'site1':
        orderObject = Site1Order
    if site == 'site2':
        orderObject = Site2Order
    if site == 'site3':
        orderObject = Site3Order
    if site == 'site4':
        orderObject = Site4Order

    order = orderObject.query.get(orderid)
    return render_template('order.html', order=order)
```

The original sites are built in PHP and have less than tidy structures and naming conventions.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Is there any way change __bind_key__ of one Model not define diferent Model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem currently with SQLALCHEMY_BINDS is that it is only used for operations like create_all() or drop_all() - you need to change the session binding for that:

```
db.session.bind = db.get_engine(app, 'site2')
```

There's work ongoing to change that but it's not in the trunk yet.

Your code could be like:

```
db.session.bind = db.get_engine(app, orderObject.__bind_key__)
order = orderObject.query.get(orderid)
```

But remember that this changes the global session and does not reset it, you'd need to do that yourself or write a contextmanager so that you can use the `with` statement for that.

If your models are identical over all databases this could also be the way to only have one class for all databases, leave the **bind_key** and query them with a special bind session object.

**Edit**: with the Flask-SQLAlchemy 0.15 Release a simple MyModel.query.filter(...) is possible for different databases if you defined __bind_key__ properly.

Comment: with the Flask-SQLAlchemy 0.15 Release a simple MyModel.query.filter(...) is possible for different databases if you defined \__bind_key__ properly.

Answer (score 1):

db.Model.metadata.tables['your model name'].info['bind_key'] = 'your bind_name'

I found a way to make things easy

Comment: Which version of flask_sqlalchemy are you using ?