# Using different binds in the same class in Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, bind, flask-sqlalchemy

I currently have multiple databases with identical Tables and Columns (but different data inside). So clearly I need to use binds to access all of them, but it's apparently not as simple as doing this:

```
class WhateverTable(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'whatevertable'
    whatever = db.Column(db.String(255))

    def __init__(self, bind=None):
        self.__bind_key__ = bind
```

and then later calling:

```
WhateverTable(bind='bind_key_here').query.filter_by(whatever='whatever').first()
```

Is there a way I can do this easily? I've tried inheriting from a table class and then defining the bind there, and while that works, it really isn't scalable.

EDIT: This :[Flask inherited classes of tables in multiple identical databases using __bind_key__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872500/flask-inherited-classes-of-tables-in-multiple-identical-databases-using-bind-k?rq=1) does sort of what I want, but I don't want to have different classes because if I ever add a new database, I'm going to have to create a new set of classes and relationships.

Comment: Did you find the way?

Comment: I have the very same requirement. How did you get through this?

Answer (score 2):

Flask-SQLAlchemy 2.1 [added support for a `binds` parameter on the session](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/commit/19c8ce02db895755feb885de42b2497d6f35059d) which should do what you want.

Comment: this issue is closed

Comment: @jeff-widman the link is broken now - can you post the answer as a text, without the link?