# Flask-Sqlalchemy multiple databases (binds) with the same model (class DB.Model)

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm a beginner with python/Flask/SQLAlchemy so sorry if my questions are dumb.

I want to create an API with Flask using Flask-SQLAlchemy as following:

1. one sqlite database for users/passwords

   SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:////path/to/users.db'

```
class User(DB.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = DB.Column(DB.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = DB.Column(DB.String(64), index=True)
    password = DB.Column(DB.String(128))
```

2. Lets say I have multiple "customers" witch a user can create using

   $ http POST http://localhost:5000/api/customers/ name=customer1

```
class Customer(DB.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'customer'
    customer_id = DB.Column(DB.Integer, primary_key=True)
    customer_name = DB.Column(DB.String, unique=True, index=True)
```

3. I need to create a separate sqlite file for each "customers" :

```
SQLALCHEMY_BINDS = {
    'customer1' = 'sqlite:////path/customer1.db',
    'customer2' = 'sqlite:////path/customer2.db',
    ...
}
```

My questions are:

1. I do not have fixed number of "customers" so I cannot create a model class for each and specify the "**bind_key**" for each. Is it possible to do this with Flask-SQLAlchemy or I need to use plain SQLAlchemy?
2. I have 3 "customers" in data/ as customer1.db, customer2.db and customer3.db.
3. I would start the application and create SQLALCHEMY_BINDS dictionary listing the files in data/ and then `DB.create_all()` on a request for a specific "customer" .
4. how can I bind to the right .db file using the Flask-SQLAlchemy
   DB.session?

   I've read [Using different binds in the same class in Flask-SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17024850/using-different-binds-in-the-same-class-in-flask-sqlalchemy)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why exactly do you want entirely separate DB files for each customer?

In any case this is easier with straight SQLAlchemy. You can create a getter function which returns a session pointing to your db file.

```
def get_session(customer_id):
    sqlite_url = 'sqlite:////path/customer%s.db' % customer_id
    engine = create_engine(sqlite_url)

    # initialize the db if it hasn't yet been initialized
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()

    return session
```

You can then use and close that session.

But without knowing your specific use case, it is difficult to understand why you would want to do this instead of just using a single SQLite database.

Comment: Hi jumbopap and thanks for the answer. this app will be used in different sites to connect to some servers and get some data. this app will also be used by several persons to look at the data(1 db) and compare with other data (other db). it would be easier just to copy the db file and put it on my db directory and the app would work. I could end up with 100 db files.

Comment: I'm new to SQLAlchemy and do not see exactly the advantage of using Flask-SQLAlchemy but I'm sure I want to use the paginate from it. I'm not sure I can use it with your approach right?

Comment: Everything you are saying can be done easier in a single DB file using relational schema, but your call.

 Plain SQLAlchemy doesn't come with pagination, but you can easily add the class in from the Flask-SQLAlchemy source.

Comment: ok, thanks. From other questions I found different ways to do it with plain SQLAlchemy but I want to know if it's possible to do it with Flask-SQLAlchemy and binds because I plan to use other packages that integrates with Flask-SQLAlchemy like Flask-Migrate and Flask-Marshmallow.

Comment: it looks like supporting multi-tenants