# How to choose database binds in flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have two database binds in Flask - 'default' and 'sus'. I used **bind_key** in Model, it worked OK.

```
class Person(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'persons'
    __bind_key__ = 'sus'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Unicode)
Person.query.get(5)
```

But now i need to execute that from 'sus' bind:

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import func

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
db.session.query(func.do_something(some_params)).first()
db.session.commit()
```

And i have got the 'default' bind, not 'sus'. What should i do?

Comment: I have found the solution. There: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872500/flask-inherited-classes-of-tables-in-multiple-identical-databases-using-bind-k?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Your `db.session` query is not using the Person model at all, so it doesn't know anything about the `__bind_key__`

Try to refactor your query so you can use `Person.query.filter(...).first()`

Comment: I dont know how i can refactor that query. Could you refactor it for me? I need to execute sql function "do_something" from other bind.